# Cannot change permission for /var/www/

Tags: server, permissions, filesystem, sudo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [problems with sudo permissions - /var/lib/sudo owned by uid](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48629/problems-with-sudo-permissions-var-lib-sudo-owned-by-uid)

I recently installed Ubuntu Server and put the GUI on so I can get the hang of Linux.
 However, I can't seem to gain access to the /var/www/ folder so I can put and edit my html files...

I tried what was on this post: [Change folder permissions and ownership](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6723/) and I still can't move files.  (Except if I use nautilus)

When I tried what Ikke suggessted, it appeared to have worked (as in no errors thrown in terminal) but when I still can't move files into the folder.

If I use nautilus and look at the permissions for /var/www it lists me as the owner (is just says my username), `Create and Delete files` for folder access.  And `---` for file access.  If I change file access to `Read and Write` it just goes back to `---` once I hit Apply Permissions to Enclosed Files.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you do `chmod` or just `chown`?

Comment: I tried both commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

/var/www is owned by root. You will need to do the following:

```
sudo chown user:user /var/www
```

Where user is your username.

Comment: I don't know what I'm looking for here.  Basically I see: a listing for `.` a green square for `..` and index.html

Comment: It might not actually be a symbolic link. I have changed the command above. See if it shows /var/www pointing to another directory.

Comment: This is all I see (for /var and /var/www) [imgur - picture](http://i.imgur.com/76CPX.jpg)

Comment: /var/www is owned by root. You will need to do chown. I will edit my answer.

Comment: I changed the owner, but it did nothing.  I still can't move my files into the folder.

Comment: Can you post the output to `ls -al /var` again

Comment: I don't know why, but when I booted the machine today I had access to the folder.  The problem may have been one of those "did you try turning it on and off again" problems...

Answer (score 1):

have you tried adding your user to the www-data group?

try this:

```
sudo usermod -G www-data -a 'your-username-here'
```

for a little more info you could look here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=919951

Comment: I saw that post before I came here, and added myself to www-data, but it didn't do anything.